# Clone repository from gitlab with custom ssh key?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to host 2 projects on 1 server and use for my first project default ssh (id_rsa) public & secret ssh key, it works, the public key is inserted as deployment key and the other one as variable in CI/CD.

For the second project I generated custom ssh key but I cannot do `git clone`. I get there all the time following error message in gitlab and on server when I try manually to do `git clone`.

```
The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried with different ssh key permissions and generated different keys, always the same problem.

Does somebody has an idea what's still missing there?

Comment: Did you try follow steps like mentioned here https://medium.com/@xiaolishen/use-multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer-7d7103ca8693 ?

Comment: Did you add the second public key to the server?